# securing of passwords in python

Tags: python, email, encryption

I am learning python so I figured I would try to make a script that automatically sends gmail emails for me.

It needs to send a login and password to my gmail account to automatically send some emails for me.

I read some of the guides here and it seems passlib is a good choice. But I am still a bit confused about how to set it up.

1. I use passlib to encrypt my password
2. The result will be stored in a hidden file in my linux vm.
3. When script runs, it needs to parse that hidden file on my vm for the hased password.
4. Here is where I am confused, I think I need to decrypt it and before sending it out? Isn't that rather insecure? Or can I send it without decryption and hopefully gmail can decrypt it?

I am using the SMTP library.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's insecure. However you encrypt the password, you're storing it *right next to the code for finding and decrypting it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passlib probably isn't actually the right choice here.  It's primarily concerned with one-way hashing of passwords.  You'd be able to use the resulting hash to verify if a user-provided password matches your hash, but not decrypt the hash.  (Older Passlib releases did have an incorrectly named `.encrypt()` method, but Passlib 1.7 renamed that to `.hash()`).

You probably want one of two things, depending on your use case:

- [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) is a python interface for saving & storing passwords in an OS-controlled "wallet".  It works cross-platform on windows, linux, etc.

However, it may prove awkward to use if the password is needing to be run from a script that's triggered outside of a logged-in desktop session.

In that case, you may want to encrypt the credentials you're using for storage, and pick a single password (provided at call time to your script, e.g. from command line prompt or env var) to decrypt those credentials.

- [cryptography](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography) is a good choice for doing something like that; it provides a number of high-level functions that don't require (too much) crypto experience, such as their [fernet encryption](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/) helpers.

Comment: I am looking at the second use case, where the script needs to run periodically without human intervention. So if I use cryptography, I would give it my password once to encrypt and store somewhere then when the script executes the unencrypted decrypt key is provided?

Answer (score 1):

The starttls() call sets up an encrypted SSL/TLS connection, so the password is not being sent in cleartext. Yes you will need decrypt the password before sending it to server.login(). Alternatively you could store the password in an environment variable and read it into python, which is not as secure, but much easier to implement.

Comment: Or in a dotfile. Anything but hardcoding the password into the script :)